# Trigger background color change of div inside a modal upon form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, liquid, liquid-layout

So I have this box:

And I need to change it back to the original color once the form has been successfully submitted so that the new color is only displayed in the load time in between.

I tried:

```js
var adding =  function() {
   $('#change-my-color').addClass('new-color');
}
var removing = function() {
   $('#change-my-color').removeClass('new-color');
}
```

```css
.original-color {
      background: red;
    }
    .new-color {
      background: blue !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="original-color" id="change-my-color">
      <form>
         <button id="trigger-color-change">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Now I trigger the color change with the button id, but what event can I use to to trigger the original color back?

Comment: How/when are you calling these functions? Is this an ajax submission? If not the entire page reset back to initial state after submission?

Comment: .addClass when user submits the form and haven't figured out yet when to call .removeClass... No, it's not ajax. And no, just the content within the modal updates (it's a shopping cart actually). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the content within the modal an `<iframe>`? If not I don't understand show your page isn't refreshing. Could you create a [mcve]..?

Comment: Ouch! I knew I had it coming... You see I'm a beginner enthusiast who's just gone past html/css into jQuery and now is trying to improve by hacking into some themes I have...  So in short: I can, yes, but it'll take me some time. Thanks for the tip and reference. I'll come back later and update my question (this is my first time at SO and I am literally falling over my laptop lol! 6 am here in Brazil). I'll do my homework! Thank you!

PS: No! There's no iframe...